# get the key of the maximum value in the dictionary among some values

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have a dictionary: `D = {'N':5, 'S':0, 'W':6, 'E':1}`  and I want to get key with maximum value among `D['N']`  and  `D['S']`.

For example I tried code  `print(lambda k: max(k['N'], k['S'])(k=D.keys()))` but it returns lambda object like this `<function <lambda> at 0x000002C7B060C1E0>`. Although I wanna get *N* in output.

Need help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass `dict.get` function as your `key` parameter in `max()`:

```
# to find the max of entire dictionary

max(D, key=D.get)
# 'W'

# to find individual keys

max(['N', 'S'], key=D.get)
# 'N'
```